# 2 lists with mismatch elements. Not sure what to assert and generate pytest cases for mismatched elements

Tags: pytest

'''Here is what I am doing
elements that should be in list1 but NOT in list2 should be ['a']
Code that I have so far'''

```py
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['b', 'c', 'd']

@pytest.mark.parametrize("list1", list1())
@pytest.mark.parametrize("list2", list2())
def test_validation(list1, list2):
    mismatch=[]
    for i in list1:
        if i not in list2:
            mismatch.append(i)
    assert mismatch
```

'''I am not sure what to assert here such that pytest generates test cases for mismatches. Appreciate your #help please'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't call lists, just specify it. Also you should pass extra argument like `expected`, to compare with actual result. This is how it should be written:

```py
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['b', 'c', 'd']

@pytest.mark.parametrize("list1, list2, expected", [list1, list2, ['a']])
def test_validation(list1, list2, expected):
    mismatch = []
    for i in list1:
        if i not in list2:
            mismatch.append(i)
    assert mismatch == expected
```

Comment: Thank you so much. These 3 lists are part of my function out of which 2 lists (input and expected) are read from csv inside a function (input_setup and expected_setup respectively) so input and expected have some common elements. My 3rd list mismatch is part of 3rd function that only prints mismatch elements from input and expected. Now how can I parametrize this and create test cases only for mismatch elements and not sure what to assert in this case. list1(which is input) is coming from input_setup func, list2(which is expected) is coming from expected_setup fun and then 3rd is mismatch